# How to make Netbeans 7.4 treat tml files as xml files?

Tags: xml, netbeans, tapestry

I'm just starting off learning old technology called Tapestry which uses tml files as their markup language. tml files are basically more or less XML files. I was curious to know how I would make my tml files to adopt the syntax (highlighting/tabular formation) from XML files in Netbeans 7.4. I tried looking in options, but I wasn't able to find it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PS: let me know if any confusion, I may be able to clear it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 8.0.2, I found it in

Tools-> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Files

Next to file extension click new enter "tml" and select XML Files in the drop down for mime-types.

I suspect it is in a similar location in version 7.4, but I don't have it installed to quickly check.